# define seed script and give example of 1 for cakephp on mysql

Tags: mysql, cakephp, test-data

Read this [article](http://hn.my/deploy)  via [Hacker monthly magazin](http://hackermonthly.com)e feb 2011.

There is a part talking about seed scripts.

1. Define what a seed script is.
2. Please give a simple example of a seed script for a webapp that runs on cakephp using MySQL as database.

Keep jargon to minimum. Metaphors and analogies are welcome.

Personally  I usually keep a separate sql dump data that i change everytime i change schema. 
This method works for me. If there is a better way, I want to know.

Comment: This:  

`Keep jargon to minimum. Metaphors and analogies are welcome.`...

Is NOT the way to ask a question - you cannot dicate _how_ you want your answer formatted/presented if you are asking on a forum out in the open on the Internet.

Did @Leo answer help? If so... then select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A seed script is a script that generates dummy data, possibly using random values or a look up table of acceptable values. The script will create the SQL queries required to insert the data into the database and may also execute the query.

Comment: so is it a sql file? I do not see Patrick's point about complaining how SQL dump is bad because the schema changes all the time. Sounds like a seed script is equally susceptible to this issue?